# undefined method `end_with?' for "rake aborted!":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I have been facing problem running rake task/commands whenever I type rake db:migrate or rake -T, it is displaying error saying undefined method `end_with?' for "rake aborted!":String (NoMethodError).Using ruby186, rails238 and gem version 1.3.3

```
rake db:migrate
/home/projects/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:48: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
/home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on': undefined method `end_with?' for "rake aborted!":String (NoMethodError)
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:322:in `trace'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `display_error_message'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:169:in `standard_exception_handling'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@global/bin/rake:19
from /home/a3logics/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

Any help I got stuck here.

Comment: Can you uninstall rubygems-bundler and see if the error still there?

Comment: Could it be that one of your rake tasks has `end_with?` in it? The method is `ends_with?`

Comment: I am sure about that it's not coming from my rake task.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error in the rake source, `end_with?` should be `ends_with?` in trace_output.rb. Try a different version of rake, I use 0.9.2.2 without any problems.