# rake aborted! 'end_with?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing rake db:migrate in an old Rails program, got into this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `end_with?' for #<Pathname:0x007fed14f11270>
/Users/dereknguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sass-3.3.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:476:in `css_filename'
/Users/dereknguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sass-3.3.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:180:in `block (2 levels) in update_stylesheets'
```

I've checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896073/undefined-method-end-with-for-rake-abortedstring-nomethoderror), , but it's not very helpful. I've tried different versions of Rake (0.8.7, 10.1.1), but didn't help. Could anyone advise?

Gemfile:

```
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.20)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.20)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.8)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.39)
Using actionpack (3.0.20)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.4)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.2.20)
Using actionmailer (3.0.20)
Using active_reload (0.6.1)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.20)
Using activeresource (3.0.20)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using multi_xml (0.5.5)
Using httparty (0.13.0)
Using mini_portile (0.5.2)
Using nokogiri (1.6.0)
Using uuidtools (2.1.4)
Using aws-sdk (1.5.8)
Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using barista (1.3.0)
Using coderay (1.1.0)
Using better_errors (1.1.0)
Using bundler (1.5.3)
Using cancan (1.4.1)
Using celerity (0.9.2)
Using culerity (0.2.15)
Using ffi (1.9.3)
Using childprocess (0.5.1)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using rubyzip (1.1.2)
Using websocket (1.0.7)
Using selenium-webdriver (2.40.0)
Using xpath (0.1.4)
Using capybara (0.4.1.2)
Using hashie (2.0.5)
Using choices (0.2.4)  
Using chronic (0.10.2)
Using climate_control (0.0.3)
Using cocaine (0.5.3)
Using configuration (1.3.4)
Using cssmin (1.0.3)
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3)
Using gherkin (2.4.21)
Using tins (1.0.1)
Using term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
Using cucumber (0.10.7)
Using cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
Using daemons (1.1.9)
Using dalli (2.7.0)
Using database_cleaner (0.6.7)
Using docile (1.1.3)
Using eventmachine (1.0.3)
Using excon (0.32.1)
Using factory_girl (1.3.3)
Using faker (1.3.0)
Using multipart-post (2.0.0)
Using faraday (0.9.0)
Using rspec-core (2.4.0)
Using rspec-expectations (2.4.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.4.0)
Using rspec (2.4.0)
Using rspec-instafail (0.2.4)
Using ruby-progressbar (1.4.2)
Using fuubar (1.2.1)
Using tilt (2.0.0)
Using haml (4.0.5)
Using headless (1.0.1)
Using heroku-api (0.3.17)
Using hpricot (0.8.6)
Using icalendar (1.1.6)
Using immortal (0.1.6)  
Using innertube (1.0.2)
Using jsmin (1.0.1)
Using jammit (0.6.6)
Using jwt (0.1.11)
Using launchy (0.3.7)
Using libxml-ruby (2.7.0)
Using mysql2 (0.2.22)
Using net-ldap (0.5.1)
Using oa-core (0.0.5)
Using oauth (0.4.7)
Using oauth2 (0.9.3)
Using oa-oauth (0.0.1)
Using paperclip (3.5.4)
Using pg (0.17.1)
Using pickle (0.4.11)
Using rack-ssl-enforcer (0.2.6)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.20)
Using rails (3.0.20)
Using rdiscount (1.6.8)
Using riddle (1.5.10)
Using rspec-rails (2.4.1)
Using sass (3.3.3)
Using simplecov-html (0.8.0)
Using simplecov (0.8.2)
Using sprockets (1.0.2)
Using sprockets-rails (0.0.1)
Using teambox-permalink_fu (1.0.3)  
Using text-hyphen (1.4.1)
Using text-format (1.0.0)  
Using thin (1.6.2)
Using thinking-sphinx (2.1.0)
Using timecop (0.7.1)
Using tmail (1.2.7.1)
Using vestal_versions (1.2.2) 
Using webrat (0.7.3)
Using whenever (0.4.2)
Using will_paginate (3.0.pre4)
```

Comment: From the error it seems the sass gem expects a String when it has a Pathname. I would try to use an earlier sass version and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried sass 3.2.12, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it seems the sass gem expects a String when it has a Pathname. I would try to use an earlier sass version and see if that changes anything.
I moved my comment here, because it seems it helped.